# C# Google Maps Api - Using the API and Getting to Know If There Is a Way Between A and B

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I am trying to code pathfinding algorithm by using Google Maps Api.

The project is an ASP.Net Web Application and I must get the shortest way between A and B but it is my job not Google Maps'.

I only need to ask Google Maps "Hey Google Is there a direct road between X and Y?" then need boolean type simple answer. (There is always a road between X and Y indirectly so Google Maps can say me the distance of road/path it is acceptable for me too).

My other question is "Is there any library for .Net to not need to use javascript or at least using javascript strings on .cs files not in aspx files?"

Thanks in advance and forgive me about my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculating route between two points you need [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). That will return you a result json/xml with distance and other details.

> The Google Directions API is a service that calculates directions
>   between locations using an HTTP request. You can search for directions
>   for several modes of transportation, include transit, driving, walking
>   or cycling. Directions may specify origins, destinations and waypoints
>   either as text strings (e.g. "Chicago, IL" or "Darwin, NT, Australia")
>   or as latitude/longitude coordinates. The Directions API can return
>   multi-part directions using a series of waypoints

A request would be something like

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&sensor=false
```

You may wanna see this article on Code project: [Google Maps API V3 for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET)

For your 2nd part of the question, I am not sure what are you asking. You can use the above API in .Net irrespective of JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that I must study on Asp.Net and JavaScript more...